# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and trying to retrieve data set from database but I've got an error as the title says

Here is the code, What's the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Admin_addNode : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var category = new category();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = category.getNode();
        DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
        DataRow myRow = tbl.Rows[i];
        string MyValue = myRow["title"].ToString();
        Response.Write(MyValue);
        }
    } 


    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

protected void Button1_Click in which "void" is red underlined in vwd

Comment: you have 2 extra braces there, one after Response.Write, and one before your button click event handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the } before "protected void Button1..."?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer you set you free from one problem, but I think there might be other, like this:

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = category.getNode();

You are creating a new DataSet then you are assigning to it something else retrieved from the method getNode(), which I suppose return another DataSet, so you lose the first one.

The way it is, it will run but you will be creating an unnecessary DataSet instance.

DataSet ds = category.getNode()